# I want the latest version of Rails when creating a new app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

The current official version of Rails is 4.0.3.

When I create a new Rails app I get version 4.0.2, and then I have to update the Gemfile and run `bundle update`.

What should I do to have the latest version of Rails (and all other default gems) on my system, such that when creating a new app it automatically has the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `gem update` it will update all installed rubygems.  This includes rails and all gems on your system.

You should be careful though since you may not want to update everything.  In that case you can specify gems individually.

`gem update rails`

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest gems you can run

```
gem update
```

To simply see what gems can be updated you can run

```
gem outdated
```

To update just the rails gem you can do

```
gem update rails
```